# Convert javascript object containg keys/values without double quotes to pure JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Given this object

```
Object { value=584, end_time="2013-11-03T07:00:00+0000"}
```

How do I convert to proper JSON?

`JSON.stringify` doesn't wrap double-quotes around keys/values without them in the object. I just get:

```
{"value":584,"end_time":"2013-11-03T07:00:00+0000"}
```

Comment: Tried iterating through the response and converting to strings?

Comment: I did that. Updated question.

Comment: That's not how you convert a number to a string.

Comment: That is correct JSON. Numbers shouldn't have quotes. You'll need to do some extra processing to convert numbers to strings

Comment: I simplified my request. Is there really no easy way to do what I need?

Comment: How is the response from `JSON.stringify` not pure JSON?  It is in fact pure JSON.  Are you wanting all values to be a string? (meaning double quoted)

Comment: Yes, I want it double-quoted. I guess I never realized ints don't get double-quotes in JSON

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should get you what you want.  I highly doubt that ChartJS is expecting integers to be strings since it is using `JSON.parse` itself and non-quoted numbers are to-spec JSON.  It looks like the output from your `JSON.stringify` is wonky.  Can you Gist/Pastebin/something the actual response from Facebook and not a messed up Firebug copy? (without the "Object", etc).  Same with the actual output you get from JSON.stringify.

Comment: i think you're right. i'm working on figuring out what is off with my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need `value` to be of type "string" you must iterate over the items and convert the type of each single item.

simple example:

```
objects=[{ value:584},{ value:123},{ value:456}];
console.log('before:',objects);
  //before: [Object { value=584}, Object { value=123}, Object { value=456}]
$.each(objects,function(i,v){objects[i].value = String(v.value)});
console.log('after:',objects);
  //after: [Object { value="584"}, Object { value="123"}, Object { value="456"}]
console.log('JSON-string:',JSON.stringify(objects));
  //JSON-string: [{"value":"584"},{"value":"123"},{"value":"456"}]
```